# how to get horizontal scroll bar for twitter timeline embedded in java web application?

Tags: javascript, twitter, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling, timeline

I need a horizontal scroll bar for twitter timeline,as of now the options provided by twitter API is vertical scroll bar or no scroll bar,how can i achieve this?

Code used:

```
<DIV class="twit">
  <A class="twitter-timeline" 
     href=<%=twitterUrl%> 
     data-widget-id=<%=twitterWidgetId%> 
     data-theme="light"  
     height="45px" 
     width="600px" 
     data-chrome="noheader nofooter" >
    <%=twitterFeed%>
  </A>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abhishek: Twitter widget provided by APIs is not yet supporting this .Hope to get this soon in further releases.

However,there can be some complex javascript solutions but that is never recommended as dymamic updation for tweets may not work.